# Roll back git repository with deployment hook

Tags: git, deployment

I have a bare git repository set up on a production server, and it uses a post receive hook to deploy whatever I push there:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/webroot git checkout -f
```

To deploy I do

```
git push production
```

From my work station, and everything is taken care of. But say I push a commit that breaks something and I want to revert asap. Will doing the following work:

```
git push production [id of commit to revert to]:master
```

IE will this still deploy everything in to the webroot correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work as expected.  You probably need to do `git push +<commit>:master` (note the +) in order to replace the bad commit at the HEAD of production master.

`+<commit>:master` is a refspec, see the [git push manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for more information about refspecs.

I would recommend reverting more explicitly without needing to force push to the production server by doing:

```
git revert <commit to revert>
git push production
```

or

```
git reset --hard <commit to revert to>
git push -f production
```

See [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Comment: If that's the case, then what does this do: git push production [id of commit to revert to]:master

Comment: Sorry, didn't know what I was talking about.

Comment: I just tested with a similar setup: a "staging" repository from which we push upstream to a bare "production" repository with a post-receive hook that updates files to a working directory. running `git push +<commit>:master` worked great as a rollback command, leaving my staging directory at the most recent commit so I can work on fixing whatever problem made me need to rollback the deployment. Thanks!

Comment: This works perfect. Then, when you want to deploy to the latest commit of the master branch, just run `git push production master` (which is the same as `git push production +HEAD:master`)